# Java regex wrapper

Tags: java, regex

Is there such a thing as a Java regex wrapper (or regex wrapper in any language). Doing a search for `"Java Regex Wrapper"` yields results about design patterns.

Ideally what I'd like is something where I could do something like this:

```
mystr(in)g.findBetween("(",")",false);
```

Where it would find the characters between ( and ) and the false is just a flag to say I don't want the regex to include the input characters.

This is not a specific example but just an example of the kind of thing that I think would be really useful.

Does something like this exist? If not is it because:

- It wouldn't work?
- Others don't think it would be useful
- No one has gotten around to it

Comment: There isn't such a thing, at least not official. You can implement it if you like. But I think that makes no sense since you can do it right with one plain regex pattern. What you are proposing is to create a thing to make easy to use pre-defined patterns.

Answer (score 2):

What you're really asking is: "Has someone written a massive library that tackles many common string searching/matching problems?"

Whether the implementation of your `findBetween(...)` is based on a regex or not is not really important.

Well the answer is really yes, but that library *is* regular expression support. It is supported in most modern languages and is very powerful and flexible.  There are also quite a lot of simpler things that most languages support: `startswith(...)`, `contains(...)`, etc.

The thing is, you have to draw the line somewhere between providing a general purpose tool like regexs, and providing bespoke functions like `startswith(...)`.

Comment: I get what you're saying about tradeoffs. I think it would be helpful if there was a separate library you could import if you needed it. I might make one, but then I'd have to learn Regex ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anything like this exist, but if you learn some regex you could make it yourselfe. A simple example:

```
String result = "mystr(in)g".replaceAll(".+[(]|[)].+", "");
System.out.println("Regex output: " + result);
```

results in:

```
Regex output: in
```